# How to create a new web character symbol recognizable by html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, character, symbols

I have checked many questions here but none has my answer. I appreciate if you direct me to the right path.

I like to make a new symbol (not a font or related to any alphabet) like creating a new language alphabets that could be recognized or translated in a browser in form of html or javascript code.

***In other words, assigning single custom character for multiple characters.(e.x 1 ch translates into 5 ch)***

I assume I need to make the font first and then assign that character. What programs do you suggest or what is the best approach?

Edit:
A better example:
Make a new character like ¢ (cent) that has     entity name --> & c e n t; and entity number --> & #  1 6 2;

Edit 2: Thank you all for your replies. I'm trying to check your links and suggestions.As I understand, there might be an issue of browser compatibility. So how about make new symbols in a text file saved on server and when the user views the file, javascript converts those symbols into a word or other standard characters?

Edit3: Sorry for any confusion guys, you are all awesome. This example might clear things.

make a new symbol that assigns to "AB". So one character that translates into two characters?

Edit4:
***This is based on Jared answer. This does work for Z and P. Now how should I add my custom font to this file (replace Z and P with my own)?
Assuming Z and P are my custom made symbols***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
 [
  <!ENTITY Z "AB">
 <!ENTITY P "DE">
   ...

  ]>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title>Extending XHTML - Example 1</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <p>My symbols are &Z; and &P;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Webdings font character 0xF6 is a cat.

Comment: Well thanks but I like to make my own symbol, cat was just an example :)

Comment: Fonts, symbols, characters are all tightly interwoven with character sets, encoding and the like. You can make a symbol and assign it to a code point in a font, then use that font in a program which recognizes that character as something... though be prepared for a world of pain as you design your own character set... more or less...

Comment: I don't mind the pain. Do you know by any chance a program that creates the font code and recognize it?

Comment: Just use Google to find a font editor.  Once you have your font, you can load it into your webpage with CSS, and set specific text on the page to use that font.

Comment: There's [Cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about), which I feel personally is annoying but to each their own. Here's a [generator page](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). If you want to make a custom font or use SVG to build glyphs or whatnot, it's just a matter of researching how to do it. SVG, possibly canvas, custom font files, etc., would work, but I think you want SVG. See the [SVG Wow site](http://svg-wow.org/).

Comment: Seeing your edit, you could use XHTML doctypes I believe and define your entity mapping using character entity encodings. I have a feeling it's not going to be as easy as you think, but you might be able to work it out. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Comment: I think you actually have pretty good odds of finding what you need in Unicode, however... it has the strangest stuff: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f638/index.htm (and UTF-8 has the same characters that Unicode has, by definition).

Comment: John your comment about Javascript used to replace entities with a symbol in some kind of file, you could do that with XSLT and XHTML.

Comment: Great example Jared. That would work for the translation part but the symbol used in example is basically "email" and I save a symbol like a circle in text file. For instance, I want to assign a character to "AB". In other words, one symbol for two characters. Forgive me if I confuse you.

Comment: I don't know how to do XSLT all that well, and it's been a while, but I really think what you're after is in there somewhere. Try the spec for XSLT, it's pretty wildly extensive: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/

Comment: I think @Brilliand's probably right too, there's a lot of crazy stuff in unicode.

Comment: Neither do I but I will read it and learn something new.Thanks so far

Comment: Check this out, this is pretty neat: http://shapecatcher.com/index.html Draw the shape you're after and it'll try to match a shape to it. You get a lot of AE characters.

Comment: I agree, there isn't really a good reference out there and because of that craziness I searched for help here

Comment: Some of these look really close to AB: http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/block/Latin_Extended-D.html Not quite, though.

Comment: So many AE lol. But it is cool. I guess it uses handwriting recognition software

Comment: Here's the unicode charts:http://www.unicode.org/charts/, and a PDF with latin characters: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Comment: Its a neat idea. To be honest my intention is to make many more symbols (cd,ccc,de,...)

Comment: [`@font-face` and `unicode-range`](http://24ways.org/2011/unicode-range).

Comment: The problem is, Jared, the existing symbols wont work for me. I need to make a huge library of symbols. So if symbols were simple, I could make so many of them. I could use something like Ꝅ and assign it to AB but there is no pattern in these symbols. I did check @font-face no luck! My goal is not that user be able to see the custom symbols but only see the translation of it. SO if my file has Ꝅ, then on browser he sees AB.

Comment: I'm still looking. It's possible I might have found a freeware tool that converts an image into a unicoded custom symbol. I'm trying it out right now.

Comment: I'm sorry Jared to put you into this. You don't have to do it. I'm highly impressed by your kindness.

Comment: I get interested in these things sometimes and I just have to go until I figure it out or decide to quit. I know there's a way to do it with XSLT transformations and probably either a custom font file definition or an image/javascript/base64 CSS data stream. I just want to see if one will work out.

Comment: Cool! Have checked Base64 tables too. It does translates characters, like for "m" it translates to twxf or something. It could be great if it was customizable and shorter. It assigns 4 characters for 1.

Comment: With a base64, I think you'd probably want to do an image map might like a PNG. Of course, if you weren't too worried about legacy support, you could do this real easy in practice with `canvas`. SVG too. It's just a matter of the different implementations and how it becomes incorporated in the markup (which is probably why you're interested in entities).

Comment: Does making png characters increase the file size? Decreasing number of characters would increase the speed of content delivery. Imagine a file with 1000 lines png symbols, would that be efficient?

Comment: It's going to be inefficient almost any way you go, which is a big consideration. I don't now how big large/high resolution you're desiring, but if they were relatively small, that would probably help. Of if they somehow worked with image sprites. Oh and the converter didn't pan out.

Comment: It would be pretty large That's why im concerned. Assuming ¢ is my custom character in my file and it translate to AB by javascript would make huge difference. The file that is sent to user would be smaller and user browser takes care of the load.

Comment: But, also, searching for that character may lead to performance issues. Ok, give this a whirl: http://jfcoder.com/test/entities.xhtml

Comment: I can take care of that with algorithm. Perhaps I was vague. In your link, the result is an image not text/string. What I meant by AB was like saying Z --> AB, or X --> FG sort of a translator ( Mersi --> Thanks) and I cant use Z because then what should i do about DZ? So need to make new symbol to translate to that

Comment: That was a demo, just to demonstrate how `ENTITY`s can hold a wide variety of data, including an image. If you literally want to use characters in a standard font map like sans-serif, that's going to be really challenging without something like SVG or `canvas`. SVG has [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html) elements. Not sure if you've looked at that or not. Designing a shape in SVG would be simpler and less data-intense than images, but look better than manual warping character kernings or whatnot.

Comment: Sure I would use SVG, no worries regarding making the symbol. Just how to assign it. And I understood your demo. The goal is to minimize what entity can hold. Using AB characters would take so much less space than a line of base64

Comment: Well, try this: http://jfcoder.com/test/entities.xhtml That has my goofy AB thingy in there, but it's a pure SVG file you can download, and I made and outputted that in Photoshop and then Illustrator (Illustrator outputs SVG, but so does Inkscape too, I believe).

Comment: Oh, this is hilarious. The SVG is a wrapper around a base64 image file. Hmm. That's not necessarily always the case, and I didn't do any compression or whatnot, just defaults. Depends on how big you need the letters to be and how big SVG lets you losslessly scale up (I think it does, not sure). But if they're going to be small letters... Small files. On the other hand, a custom font map is probably starting to look a bit less of a hassle. EDIT: Scratch that, at least the SVG I made is definitely lossy when it's blown up.

Comment: lol I checked the code too. It is base64 indeed and it is possible to change height and width (1px 1px) and If I enlarge the screen, I can see a dot. However, svg file is 4kb and I guess a single ch "a" might take 8 bits or so. Im not sure about the sizes. Take a look at OP. This is based on your answer

Comment: Alright, check the page out again: http://jfcoder.com/test/entities.xhtml That's a 1kb file, too.

Comment: And realize I know that's ugly with a capital F. But it's a proof of concept.

Comment: It's not ugly at all, its actually very cool, great method. I can automate this to create tons of characters in no time. How do you propose to translate your svg to string?

Comment: String? What do you mean? Are you talking about embedding it into a custom `ENTITY` like the others?

Comment: At this point in time, I really think you should strongly consider SVG, even if you do make a custom font for at least some characters. This is a file with an embedded font I found: http://jfcoder.com/test/font-embedded.svg That file, found at Google Code, is only 3kb with three custom letters (glyphs) embedded, and could be minified to probably half that.

Comment: What I mean is you have made AB SVG. Now when javascript reads the file and sees your svg character, it echos the string "AB" on screen. Or lets put it this way, it puts A and B next to each other. Suppose u made Apple svg and so js echos the word not the image (puts A P P L E characters next to each other)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Are you wanting to grab the text formatted from the SVG file? At this point, Javascript has not been involved, nor does it really need to be (give or take a desired something or other). But what's on the screen is how the browser renders the SVG. So I'm a little confused.

Comment: @john206: I suggest you look into the CSS `@font-face` declaration; that's how you'll need to include your custom font.  It might not work well with the other methods listed here.

Comment: SVG is like an image right? When JS recognizes the image, it outputs a string (name of the image) not the SVG image itself.

Comment: SVG can represent an image (as you saw with the base64 original attempt), but look at the source of the .svg files on that page I've linked; that's a text a file, there's no image. I don't believe that Javascript can directly access the underlying display data in such a way as it would actually be that special text display you're after, although I'm not real super well versed on the Javascript SVG libraries (other than some functions are universally supported). When do you envision Javascript manipulating the `AB` SVG object, and what would it do with it?

Comment: Brilliand, @face-font shows my custom font but it doesn't actually outputs strings. If I have 10 custom characters next to each other with no space, when translated, that 10 characters becomes, for ex, 20 standard characters. That means each custom character represents two standard characters. If my SVG is image of a Circle, JS outputs the string AB, so user will see AB and SVG is only exists on my server file

Comment: SVG is a vector format like Illustrator, which is why you should be able to grow and shrink it losslessly. The file represents an algorithm that draws the shapes. Base64-based SVG files notwithstanding.

Comment: No Jared. I have no intention to access the code inside SVG. Recall the experiment when the Bell rings, dog becomes hungry? Same thing here, when custom image/svg is recognized, output is a string

Comment: I apologize for any confusion I made. I appreciate the efforts u guys put.

Comment: You mean have the browser interpret the SVG's display as a string? Like Base64 (at the browser)? What are you going to do with the string? (Ironically, I know `canvas` can do this easily, but it's still a little undersupported but wildly awesome.)

Comment: Yes you got it! You see some files you open in editor appear in binary format or like weird characters? But eventually they are interpreted as something else. The key is to write a js code to interpret it. If I had an png image, as Brilliand said, we could use jquery/js to grab img tag and replace it but when I load my custom font, there is a font file not a single image.

Comment: [SVGWeb](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/) is a comprehensive SVG Javascript platform. They have [very extensive demos](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/samples/demo.html?name=svgopen&svg.render.forceflash=false) on their site, too. Couple hundred with toggles, buttons, rendering modes, etc. Including the underlying markup.

Comment: With Javascript, are you wanting to have a number of glyphs (20?) that represent 10 characters, and that Javascript can manipulate each glyph and dual-glyph character set independently?

Comment: JS sees a custom glyph Z but instead of outputing Z on screen, it outputs two glyphs, so for ex. it outputs GH. Because of this, I only need to save Z on my file but the output is 2 glyphs (buy one get second one free!). So if my server file has 10 glyphs, it translates to 20 glyphs

Comment: Because the one glyph Z is composed of GH? Does Z only represent a transient state like Base64 encoded, but is not "screen" reprsentable, but once it's "unzipped" it's actually two different "files"? What is the end result you're wanting, in the browser? What are your users going to see/get? You're not wanting to do all this due to data constraints or something?

Comment: Suppose we had a symbol/glyph for each two characters. Z doesnt need to contain GH in its code. Z only says when JS finds me, echo G and H glyphs. Yes, browser is the end result. Actually there is no physical zipping here. and yes, there is a need to reduce data size.

Comment: Please take a look at question. I changed it using Z and P, it does work, now instead of Z and P, use custom glyph

Comment: Ok, so there is no Z, that's just what you were calling the intermediate transport content that contained the values. Are you imagining the server is going to output a string meant for the client's browser in some neutral format (this is what Base64 is about, it's a method of representing content in probably any format as ASCII and thus likely to be lossless across different server environments). Or are you imagining the browser receiving the SVG content? (Keeping in mind you can put the SVG markup in the page request itself, instead of another download requirement).

Comment: Alright, so something like `<!ENTITY Z "gobbledygookwhatever">` and that wherever `&z;` is on the page, the two glyphs `&z;` represents gets inserted... Somehow?

Comment: Browser does receive the SVG but it doesnt load it. Consider the SVG as a command. Well no matter what way browser receives SVG (base 64 format), it loads two different ch. Z should actually exists. Imagine I saved a file with this content: ZPPZPZPPZPZPZPZPZPZPZPZZPZPZP, when browser reads my file and loads custom Z and P glyphs, it outputs AEBDBDAE............ Z=AE, P=BD

Comment: Yes you are right. Your code works if I use Z, but try @ instead of Z. It doesnt work. Perhaps @ is recognized as something else for browser. Now imagine I have a square svg Instead of Z and put square in place of Z. You see the application of this? I only saved ZP on my file but browser output AEBD, interpreter(JS) is on client size so my server doesnt have to take the hit and also saves space.

Comment: I think I might have a demonstration of how to use a template and Javascript to load the SVG. Now, you're not working on some kind of glyph-based data encryption, right? `;)`

Comment: I thought of that for encryption but it creates security hole, so no use for that :) only works on server side. Reading the source file is not hard. the beauty is JS does the work, so less data to be loaded and user cpu works harder. This would work for image at least.

Comment: If my custom ch takes more space than one standard ch, it defeats the purpose. So size matters

Comment: Im sure you got tired. Plz let me know about the template when you had a chance. So far was a great talk

Comment: I'm still here. I needed to work on the script. What browser do you use? FF?

Comment: yes, is ur code only compatible with FF?

Comment: Yes. I'm having an issue with IE and Chrome due to a `script.innerHTML` tag issue, but if you view it in Firefox, it works: http://jfcoder.com/test/dynglyph.xhtml

Comment: It does work on FF. Nice code. Would it work on all browsers if u load the svg?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I've been arguing over something silly in another question, so I got distracted. Let me see if I can get it worked out.

Comment: Removing `//<![CDATA[//]]>` from the `text/template` script tag is proving more challenging than I anticipated...

Comment: Making codes work in all browsers is always painful

Comment: We could ignore those if the `!ENTITY` approach wasn't requiring us to stick with XHTML. Otherwise, we'd just get rid of it; HTML doesn't require it in `script` tags. No big deal, it's just a little more to do.

Comment: You are right. I would do more research tomorrow and play with code to see if works. So far thanks a lot. Hope I learn more from you tomorrow or any other time. I dont know what time it is over there but it should be late.

Comment: Well, now it works after I took them out, and the XML parsers are complaining. IE9 and Chrome are working with the script.

Comment: yeah works in chrome/safari but not in FF. Could use browser detection and specify code for browser type

Comment: Huh. No, it has to do with that `CDATA` business; that's why I had it in there, but it works without it in the others, just not in Firefox. It may be that for security reasons, FF empties the `script` tags. There's only a `A B` left in Firebug.

Comment: got you. I used another symbol (Ö) in xhtml and code works. So, here is the thing. Lets say u have image saved as base64 (could be png,jpg) which then is converted to custom font on server side. Now load the image with img tag. Browser first interprets custom font and translates it to base64 and then image. what would be your suggestion for this?

Comment: Large? How large? Base64, like XML, is not good for everything; it can be considered an expensive step to take only when you need to. If you have a large image, maybe larger than 250k-300k in size compressed, I wouldn't be adding processor-intensive steps like symbol encoding and DOM manipulation/insertion. You may not notice the impact, but to me that's not what base64 is for.

Comment: Shaun Inman, who also helped develop sIFR and who it's named, has [Cacheer](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/css_ssc), which is all about CSS file caching with the sprites and other assets base64'd within the files. It's been controversial; if you've never heard of it, you might try to find some of the arguments for and against it.

Comment: Not that large, just regular web images. By the way, base64 to encoded format would reduce the size physically without losing data or being zipped. Only thing is left is to translate the delivered code using decoding method

Comment: uploaded images are in sprite format already. Have heard a little bit and some methods are good

Comment: You're jumping through a lot of hoops to shrink your site's footprint in transport. Are you encoding your sprite files too?

Comment: Yes.php code is used to convert images to sprites (when images are added to site). Then converted to base64. This is what I have done so far. Next step would be encoding the code to smaller size and eventually load on client side

Comment: Alright, it looks like it's working in all the Windows browsers (my Safari for some reason never, ever runs).

Comment: Sweet, it works on all browsers :) thank you.

Comment: hope I find a way to interpret the custom code later

Comment: I imagine there's a less-messy way of doing it; I'm not the first one to do this, but maybe most don't bother with XHTML doctypes, either. I think you could possibly combine it with custom entities and something like a [Mustache templates](http://mustache.github.com/#demo), that could be interesting to pull off.

Comment: XHTML is new for me so I need to dig into it. I might use mustache or alternatives like Stylus and Jade in node. Indeed, it would make things much smoother.

Comment: There's also [template-based CoffeeScript](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco#readme) and (Underscore.js)[http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template].

Comment: it looks interesting! SO many new things im learning lol

Comment: Well, I think you could do things along the lines of `<!ENTITY o "{i-o}">`, which could shorten the bits needed for things like embedding `img` tags within the markup. Then, as brialiin suggested earlier, selector and "template" those values into the real values. The only thing is the last part could be expensive to pull off on more than a regular basis. I think that I may finally be understanding what you're actually doing, and why you talk about it like "symbol A to O/R". Interesting.

Comment: Entity is very helpful here. If this works out, files are highly reduced. Imagine you zip them as well and that would be extra fantastic.

Comment: You can do gzip (don't know if you knew that or not), too, as part of the message transport, so it's compressed in transit.

Comment: yeah thats what i meant. even further compression can be applied after encoding. This is what others usually do but sometimes in process of compression resolution goes down or if file is too large, decompressing delays results; so encoding approach would shorten the file without losing data

Comment: Also, if you do @john206 when you type out a name, instead of john206, the first will send a notification to that user through SO. You can also use ticks around code to give it that `grey` background in comments, and single and double asterisks around the text represents italics and bold, respectively. `[title goes here](link goes here)` is how you create a link with text. There's others, but those are the ones I've used enough to remember.

Comment: Here is the demonstration of the script which swaps the entity `&z;` to a `{ab}` placeholder, then Javascript swaps that value for an image. See: http://jfcoder.com/test/templatesvg.xhtml I believe it's running in all browsers without any issues.

Comment: @JaredFarrish cool didnt know that.tnx. Your code works on browsers and its very simple and effective!

Comment: @JaredFarrish - can you create a chat room for you and john to continue this conversation. Also, can these comments be purge now that there is an accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an option for you, I'm not quite sure. Pretty much, if you use XHTML and/or XLST, you could possibly achieve what you're looking for in custom-defined characters. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
[
  <!ENTITY mailto "mailto:">
  <!ENTITY username "gabriel">
  <!ENTITY arobase "@">
  <!ENTITY hostname "gabsoftware">
  <!ENTITY tld ".com">
  <!ENTITY email "&username;&arobase;&hostname;&tld;">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Extending XHTML - Example 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>My email is &email;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/entities.xhtml

You'll see the SGML `ENTITY` element, which by the way I believe HTML5 is no longer going to belong to anymore. Whether or not you can embed an image in those entities or through an XLST transformation to achieve your goal I haven't figured out yet.

For many more examples and options, see this page:

[Extending XHTML with XML, XSLT, entities, CDATA sections and JavaScript](http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/extending-xhtml-with-xml-xsl-transformations-entities-cdata-sections-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SGML Entity declaration to create a new character entity.  This should work in all languages that inherit from SGML including HTML and XML, but I would be sure to test this in all supported user agents just to be sure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_entity

Comment: HTML and XML are subsets of SGML, not supersets.  Have you tested this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard characters (a-Z, A-Z, 0-9, !, @, #, $, etc), ,you could make a PHP variable that has the translation as the page is being rendered (JavaScript is after the page is rendered/downloaded).

```
<?php
  $from = "A";
  $into = "ABCD";
  $content = "This is A whole lot of page content";

  echo preg_replace("$from, $into, $content);
 // will output "This is ABCD whole lot of page content"
?>
```

Could work with special fonts too, i'd imagine, or even swapping `$from` into `<img src=pic/of/chars.png" />`.

Comment: Douglas, unfortunately I wont use standard characters. Imagine a text file with 1000 lines of custom characters. If I use php, its a load on server, so I should do that with javascript.